# How to find the original index after removing rows?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix A of size 15000*1000. I remove 1000 all-zero rows out of it, and get a new matrix B of size 14000*1000. Let's say I choose row 10000 from the new matrix B. How can I find the original index of this row in the original matrix A? In the other word, I want to find the original index according to the new index of some row in my data. For instance, if the 14999th row in the original matrix A turns to be the 14000th row in the new matrix B，how can I derive 14999 when only 14000 in B is given? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a step back and use the index vector used to delete(or select) rows from the original matrix. Let's say you had operations like these:

```
A = randn(150,100); % Sample A matrix
rejectIdx = randi(150,10,1); % 10 rows which should be removed (selected at random here)
B = A; B(rejectIdx,:) = []; % Remove the ten rows from A
```

Create a vector of row indexes and remove the row indexes using the same `rejectIdx` variable

```
origIdx = 1:150; origIdx(rejectIdx) = []; % Save row indexes and remove index using the same idx
```

Now to find which row in A corresponds to the ith row in B one could simply execute

```
A(origIdx(i),:)
```